# Right truncate of attribute to string of length 40 in perl

Tags: perl, substr

I want to right truncate a value of attribute to string of length 40 using regex in Perl.

I tried to do it without using regex, only `substr()` but it’s not working.

```
$attribute = substr ($attribute , -1 ,40);
```

Comment: For future reference, "it's not working" is a very inadequate way to describe a problem. For this question, you might consider using expected result vs actual result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Right truncate" equals to using `substr()` the usual way:

```
$attribute = substr($attribute,0,40)
```